# Python lxml Xpath import problem - I need to remove leading and trailing [' '] appended to the imoprted value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, lxml

I'm trying to monitor whether a specific canonical URL is changed on a Webpage via Python and lxml.

The idea is to have a list of URL with the correct canonical URLs in an Excel sheet, which is imported into Python and then periodically checked against the live site (via lxml and an Xpath). If a change is detected, then flag is set to FALSE.

The problem: When I import via lxml additional characters are imported which means my True / False matching never works. e.g lxml will create `['https://www.example.com/canonical.html']` instead of `https://www.example.com/canonical.html`

`new_canonical = tree.xpath('//link[@rel="canonical"]/@href')`

I'm a noob at python, but have been pulling my hair out all day to the point of even appending the extra [' '] charcters to the URLs in the excel sheet (so that they match up - but it doesn't work).

In short, I need `new_canonical = tree.xpath('//link[@rel="canonical"]/@href')` to produce https://www.example.com/canonical.html instead of ['https://www.example.com/canonical.html']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `xpath` method returns a Python [List](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm).

All you need to do is to obtain the first element from the list.

```
new_canonical = tree.xpath('//link[@rel="canonical"]/@href')
my_url = new_canonical[0]
```